# Android Studio 1.4 compiling with a lower API than API 23 (example API 22)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded the new Android Studio 1.4.

I want to write and compile code with API 22 and not API 23. Even if I change the `targetSdkVersion` to 22 in the Gradle and the `compileSdkVersion` to 22 (and of course sync it) I get this errors:

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>           org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sedkol
>   /Code/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

Also when I change the `compileSdkVersion` and the `targetSdkVersion` to 22 the

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

are both highlighted and when I hover over it says:

This support library should not use a different version (23) than the `compileSdkVersion (22)`
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your `targetSdkVersion`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the appcompat version to the same as your target SDK:

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'`

And if needed also download the new needed items from Android SDK

Comment: Error:(12, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.

Comment: Error:(4, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sedkol/Code/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: /Users/sedkol/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-10-09 at 13.27.12.png maybe if i uninstall Android 6?

Answer (score 0):

You must change the **appcompat version** to the same as your **targetSdkVersion** or **compileSdkVersion**.

In your case it will be:

```
dependencies {
    compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    ...
}
```

After change the appcompat version you must sync project with gradle files.